# Apache SSHD client get server public key

Tags: java, ssh, openssh, sshd, apache-mina

I am trying to get the public key of a server. This is what I tried:

```
val serverKey = sshClient.connect("dyn mem", "localhost", "2222")
  .verify()
  .getSession()
  .getKex()
  .getServerKey()
```

The problem is get the result of `getServerKey()` is null...

How can I get the public key of a SSH server with the Apache SSHD client.

Comment: Feedback on existing answer? Works? Doesn't works?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am extremely busy, will test it when I have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `connect()`, and the subsequent key exchange are async operations, so a couple of waits are needed.  E.g. :

```
        ConnectFuture connectFuture = client.connect(username, host, 22);
        connectFuture.await(5000);

        ClientSession session = connectFuture.getSession();
        session.waitFor(Arrays.asList(ClientSessionEvent.WAIT_AUTH), 5000);

        session.getKex().getServerKey();
```

Comment: It did not solve the problem but I am sure it has something to do with it. When I debug and set the breakpoint after the connection it works.

Comment: It looks like the key exchange after the session has connected is async too, so there is a further wait for this.  This is also in the answer now.